# How to draw half of the border around a box using css

Tags: html, css

I have a design in which I have to draw half of the border around a text. The method I am using to hide half of the border around the box forces me to use an absolutely positioned child element, which goes out of the flow of the relatively positioned parent. The consequence is that, when the length of the text increases, the parent box does not grow with the child and the text goes over the border. I want the parent to grow in height to surround the text.

What should I do to achieve the desired design and make the parent surround the child text?

```css
.mask-right-half {
  width: 70%;
  height: 101%;
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
}

.black-border {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  min-height: 250px;
  max-height: 350px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div class='black-border'>
  <div class='mask-right-half'></div>
  <div class='text'>
    <p>
      This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This
      testing text.This testing text. This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This
      testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This
      testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testin
    </p>

  </div>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4oupmo03/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply consider `linear-gradient` as `border-image` and you will have what you need with less code:

```css
p {
 padding:20px;
 border:2px solid;
 border-image:linear-gradient(to right,transparent 50%,#000 50%) 20;
}
```

```html
<p>
  This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.
</p>
<p>
  This testing text
</p>
<p>
   This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text. This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.
</p>
```

Here is another idea with pseudo element:

```css
p {
 padding:20px;
 position:relative;
}
p:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  left:50%;
  border:2px solid;
  border-left:none;
}
```

```html
<p>
  This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.
</p>
<p>
  This testing text
</p>
<p>
   This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text. This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.
</p>
```

Another way using linear-gradient as background *(useful if you want to manage border separately)*

```css
p {
 padding:20px;
 background:
 linear-gradient(to right,#000,#000) 100% 0/60% 2px no-repeat,
 linear-gradient(to right,#000,#000) 100% 100%/50% 2px no-repeat,
 linear-gradient(to right,#000,#000) 100% 0/2px 100% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<p>
  This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.
</p>
<p>
  This testing text
</p>
<p>
   This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text. This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks. someone marked the question negative. can you explain why?

Comment: @azamkhan if it was me i can explain you :) but it's not me

Comment: I tried the pseudo element. but that is the same as mine. Your first one is working fine for me.

Comment: @azamkhan for the pseudo element don't forget the relative position on parent container

Comment: also the first approach is reducing the mark up considerably.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `.text` element does not need to be positioned absolutely.

```css
.mask-right-half {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  left:-1px;
  top:-1px;
  padding:0 0 2px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
 }

.black-border {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  min-height: 250px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div class='black-border'>
  <div class='mask-right-half'></div>
  <div class='text'>
    <p>
      This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This
      testing text.This testing text. This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This
      testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text lkjlkjlkjlkjklkljlkjlkj;l kjl lkj lkj lkjk;ljl j;lj;lkj ;lkj lkjlkj ;lkj;lkj;lj ;lj ;lj;l
    </p>
    <p>
      This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This
      testing text.This testing text. This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This
      testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text lkjlkjlkjlkjklkljlkjlkj;l kjl lkj lkj lkjk;ljl j;lj;lkj ;lkj lkjlkj ;lkj;lkj;lj ;lj ;lj;l
    </p>
    <p>
      This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This
      testing text.This testing text. This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This
      testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text lkjlkjlkjlkjklkljlkjlkj;l kjl lkj lkj lkjk;ljl j;lj;lkj ;lkj lkjlkj ;lkj;lkj;lj ;lj ;lj;l
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Edit

To simplify the markup, I might even recommend using [`pseudo-element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) for the border mask:

```css
.black-border:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  left: -1px;
  top: -1px;
  padding: 0 0 2px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: -1;
}

.black-border {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  margin: 2em;
  padding: 1.5em;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='black-border'>
  <p>
    This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.
  </p>
</div>

<div class='black-border'>
  <p>
    This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This
    testing text.This testing text. This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This
    testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text lkjlkjlkjlkjklkljlkjlkj;l kjl lkj lkj lkjk;ljl j;lj;lkj ;lkj lkjlkj ;lkj;lkj;lj ;lj ;lj;l
  </p>
</div>

<div class='black-border'>
  <p>
    This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This
    testing text.This testing text. This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This
    testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text lkjlkjlkjlkjklkljlkjlkj;l kjl lkj lkj lkjk;ljl j;lj;lkj ;lkj lkjlkj ;lkj;lkj;lj ;lj ;lj;l
  </p>
  <p>
    This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This
    testing text.This testing text. This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This
    testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text lkjlkjlkjlkjklkljlkjlkj;l kjl lkj lkj lkjk;ljl j;lj;lkj ;lkj lkjlkj ;lkj;lkj;lj ;lj ;lj;l
  </p>
  <p>
    This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This
    testing text.This testing text. This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This
    testing text.This testing text.This testing text.This testing text lkjlkjlkjlkjklkljlkjlkj;l kjl lkj lkj lkjk;ljl j;lj;lkj ;lkj lkjlkj ;lkj;lkj;lj ;lj ;lj;l
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it but the mask was hiding half of the text. But yours is working fine

Comment: I think @TemaniAfif has an [even more efficient idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48995775/how-to-draw-half-of-the-border-around-a-box-using-css#answer-48995821), skipping the mask and setting the border itself as a pseudo-element.

Comment: Thanks. you guys are awesome.